# ng-pattern for password text to accept all special characters and numbers, alphabets

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

**Html**

```
<form novalidate class="css-form">
    username <input type="text" 
    ng-pattern="/^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@('@')$!%*#?&])[A-Za-z\d$@('@')$!%*#?&]{8,20}$/" ng-model="user.email" required /><br />
</form>
```

Above pattern is working fine for below symbols

```
@ # $ % & ! *
```

But I want to allow all special characters like

```
{ } [ ] < > ( ) ^ + - = ; : ' " / \ |
```

[**plunkr link**](http://plnkr.co/edit/OziBKVqDtI3XLjMSipqF?p=preview)

How to include all special characters  in that pattern that should work for password?

Comment: use escape character in your regex

Comment: @azad how to escape the all the special characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following `ng-pattern`:

```
ng-pattern="/^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@('@')$!%*#?&{}[\]<>()^+=;:'&quot;/\\|-])[A-Za-z\d$@('@')$!%*#?&{}[\]<>()^+=;:'&quot;/\\|-]{8,20}$/"
```

Note that `\` and `]` are escaped in the character class with `\` and the double quotes are represented as a `&quot;` HTML entity. The hyphen does not need escaping *when at the character class end*.

See the [updated plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/blXrBPU9O1JebOgG2Bhk?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

Escape special symbols by "\" char before each special symbol.