# regular expression not working as expected, what gone wrong here?

Tags: angularjs

I have a text box for password which should accept 1 letter  1 special character at least. and it should not be less than 8 character and should not be greater than 15 character . but now its accepting more than 15 character . where it gone wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/u1fm0jLo/243/

```
 ng-pattern="/((?=.*\W).{8,15}$)/"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
ng-pattern="/^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$&*])[A-Za-z\d@$&*]{8,15}$/"
```

> (?=.*[A-Za-z]) - Assert a string has at least one Alphabet;
>
> (?=.*\d) -Assert a string has at least one number;
>
> (?=.*[@$&*]) - Assert a string has at least one of this character;
>
> [A-Za-z\d@$&*]{8,15} - Characters (Only numbers and letters) length
>   should be between 8 and 15

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller("ctrl", function($scope) {

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <label>Password</label>
  <form name="form">
    <input type="password" style="width: 600px" class="form-control" name="Password" id="Password" ng-pattern="/^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*[@$&*])[A-Za-z@$&*]{8,15}$/" ng-model="User.Password" ng-minlength="7" ng-class="submitted?'ng-dirty':''" required />
    <br/>
    <span class="error" ng-show=" (form.Password.$dirty || submitted) && form.Password.$error.required">Required</span>
    <span class="error" ng-show=" (form.Password.$dirty || submitted) && form.Password.$error.minlength">Mini 8 characters</span>
    <span class="success" ng-show=" (form.Password.$dirty || submitted) && form.Password.$error.pattern">Invalid</span>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: i dont want number. just want a special charector.

Comment: Then try this ng-pattern="/^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*[@$&*])[A-Za-z@$&*]{8,15}$/"

Comment: and one more issue, i am not supposed to use @ symbol. i am using cshtml, So @ symbol will give error

Comment: In this (?=.*[@$&*]), within braces [@$&*] put whichever symbol you want to use. forexample if you don't want to use '@' just remove from this [$&*]

Comment: how to make it all special charector, without specifying each?

Comment: I don't think it is possible. You have to specify the characters in the pattern

Comment: ng-pattern for password text to accept all special characters and numbers, alphabets (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40989339/ng-pattern-for-password-text-to-accept-all-special-characters-and-numbers-alpha). You will get your answer here.

Answer (score 0):

Is this you are expecting? `\W` matches any non-word character. Same as `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]`

```
/((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*\W).{8,15}$)/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern

```
ng-pattern="^(?=.*[a-zA-z])(?=.*[$@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*?&]{8,15}"
```

> (?=.*[a-zA-z])  -> This checks for at least 1 alphabet
>
> (?=.*[$@$!%*?&]) -> This checks for at least 1 special character
>
> [A-Za-z\d$@$!%*?&]{8,15} -> Checks for total length is > 8 and < 15