# What is the format for pattern String in pattern Attribute?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I want to have a password or form pattern defined by myself but I can't find in Internet how to do that customized ones.

I know there are ng-pattern in angularJs and pattern attribute in HTML but my problem is what is the format for that and what does '{ }', '[ ]', '/' mean? And how to set AND, OR conditions in that?

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42217998/regular-expression-not-working-as-expected-what-gone-wrong-here/42218346#42218346 . Check this post for further understanding

Comment: What if I want the first letter to start with 'A'? Can you explain me in deeper like why it starts with ?=.*

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570896/what-does-mean-in-a-regular-expression Check it out ..

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use pattern attribute in HTML and define your custom pattern in it.

See below:

```
<input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="password"
pattern="^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*?&]{8,}" required="required" />
```

This pattern will have a check that password contains lowercase, uppercase, special character and numeric value.

Comment: 1) Why Did you started with '^' ?  2) what is (?=.*\d) in the middle?  3) I want my password to start with 'A' so what should I include?

Comment: you need to learn regex usage first if you are not familiar with.  ^ will matches starting a string. ? will  match zero or one occurrences of the preceding element. * matches zero or more occurrences of the preceding element. (.) matches any single character

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ng-pattern="/^([A_])+(([\._\-\~\=\+\?\*\@])*([a-zA-Z0-9])*)*$/"
```

> [A_]- This checks that your pattern starting with Alphabet A.

- / ->  Charachters delimit the regular expression
- ^ -> Match at the beginning of the line
- . followed by * -> Match any character (.), any number of times
  (*)
- $ -> End of the line